Bookmarklet is replacing the entire body with the text from new style definition
So I'm trying to make a couple quick bookmarklets to help me with using Jira:

Remove the sidebar
Enlarge the text editor area

The following bits of code work fine in the dev console:
document.getElementsByClassName('jira-editor-container')[0].style.height='1000px';
document.getElementById('viewissuesidebar').style.display='none';

But when I alter them to,
javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('jira-editor-container')[0].style.height='1000px';
javascript:document.getElementById('viewissuesidebar').style.display='none';

And use them as bookmarklets, the entire page body is replaced with the style values (eg. 1000px or none).
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't understand the disconnect between the dev console working and the bookmarklet not working.

When you run in the console, what's the output?   That output is sent to the document when it's a bookmarklet.  You could possibly also add ;return false; or ;return null at the end to stop the output.

Ahhhhh, wrapping the code in an IIFE got it to work:
javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByClassName('jira-editor-container')[0].style.height='1000px';}())
javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('viewissuesidebar').style.display='none';}())

Can't believe I didn't think of that originally!
